# Windows10: Import the start menu of an existing user account to a new user account

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Can I import my Windows 10 start menu from a **broken** user account into a new user account? If I still have the old user account's folder in `C:\users\old_account`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's a bit complicated but yes it's possible:*

1. export the start menu database from the excisting user to a reg file:

   1a. if your old user account is still accessible do it logged in to that account

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount`

   1b. if not load the registry from the old account though the: "ntuser.dat" file

   - in regedit: select "HKEY_USERS" key
   - file > load hive...
   - select "ntuser.dat" from `c:\Users\[olduser]\`
   - the old users registry is now loaded in the "HKEY_USERS" key
2. in youw new user account delete the excisting start menu structure in the registry located at:
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount`
   by deleting the full "DefaultAccount" folder and its contents.
3. edit the exported .reg file from step 1.
   change the `HKEY_USERS` root to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and save the file.
4. import the edited reg file to your new user account by doubleclicking the .reg file.
5. logout and login
6. open your startmenu and see if it is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the Windows 10 'Tiles' then a simple solution is to login as new user & copy Start Menu shortcuts from old to new user:

`C:\Users\UserNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-recover-the-programs-disappeared-from-the-all-programs-of-the-start-menu-eeekb-e93a1a2a-2fc6-707f-2060-1a79d52ebf4b

Comment: yes this one I knew this folder from previous versions of Windows. These were easy times :) The problem is that windows10 focusses now on "the tiles" so I did an effort to build a nice non "spammy looking titleboard", which took a lot of time so I did not want to redo it from scratch. Hope there comes an easyer way in the future like drag and drop.

Comment: User independent text which can be pasted into Windows Run dialog to open the folder for you: `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`